# For which values of $b$ does $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{e^{\left(b+1\right)k}+k^2}{3^{2k}+\sqrt{k}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the value(s) of $b$ for which the following series converges:
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\frac{e^{\left(b+1\right)k}+k^2}{3^{2k}+\sqrt{k}}$$

I found this problem on an old Calculus 2 practice exam, and I can't seem to crack it using any method I know of. Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which methods did you try? And why doesn’t work? Please share your effort.

Comment: Either there is a typo in the summation or this is a trick question. The expression after the sigma doesn't depend on $n$ and can be factored out. This is divergent for any $b$. If this is a sum over $k$ instead, then the answer below should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$0\le {e^{(b+1)k} +k^2\over 3^{2k}+ \sqrt{k}}\le {e^{(b+1)k} +k^2\over 9^{k}} =\left ( {e^{b+1}\over 9}\right )^k+{k^2\over 9^k}$$ The series with terms $k^2/9^k$ converges (by the ratio test).  Hence the series converges if $$e^{b+1}<9, \ \ {\rm i.e.}\ \ b<\ln 9 - 1 $$
The condition is also necessary since $${e^{(b+1)k} +k^2\over 3^{2k}+ \sqrt{k}}\ge {e^{(b+1)k} \over 3^{2k}+\sqrt{k}}\ge {1\over 2} \left ( {e^{b+1}\over 9}\right )^k$$ On the way we have used $9^k\ge 2^k\ge k\ge \sqrt{k}.$

The problem can be as well solved by the ratio test.

Answer (score 1):

Since $3^{2k}$ increases much faster than $\sqrt{k}$ we can omit the term $\sqrt{k}$ for convergence analysis. Now we want the denominator to increase faster. Clearly $b=-1$ works. For that matter, any $b \le -1$ works. Even $b=1$ works since $3$ is larger than $e$. But larger values of $b$ make the expression diverge.